# Fourier transform of rect

Tags: fourier-transform

$\newcommand{\rect}{\operatorname{rect}}$Given $f(x) = \cos(x)\rect(x^2-1) $ , I have to calculate the Fourier transform.

$$F(p) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2\pi} \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \cos(x)\rect(x^2-1) e^{-ipx} \, dx $$

Now, those should be two rects centered in $-1$ and $1$, right?

Should I integrate considering every rect's span $1 $ or 

$-\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$, $-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$  and  $+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ , $+\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$?

where 
$$ \rect(t) =
  \begin{cases}
    1       & \quad \text{if } t \in [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}] \\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

Edit:
So it should be

$F(p) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt2\pi} \int_{-\sqrt\frac{3}{2}} ^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}} e^{ix(1-p)} + e^{-ix(1+p)}dx + \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}} ^{\sqrt\frac{3}{2}} e^{ix(1-p)} + e^{-ix(1+p)}dx $

right?

Edit II:

$\frac{e^{-i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1-p)}- e^{-i\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}(1-p)}}{i(1-p)} + \frac{e^{i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1+p)}- e^{i\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}(1+p)}}{i(1+p)} + \frac{e^{i\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}(1-p)}- e^{i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1-p)}}{-i(1-p)} +\frac{e^{-i\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}(1+p)}- e^{-i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1+p)}}{-i(1+p)}$

So I get this, that I should be able to group up in a sinc, maybe?

Comment: What is $rect()$?

Comment: According to [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function), one has a.e. $rect(x^2-1) = \chi_{(-\sqrt{3/2}, -\sqrt{1/2})\cup (\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{3/2})}(x)$.

Comment: @kimchilover I updated the question.

Comment: Following @Gribouillis's correct intuition, you should integrate only over those $x$ values where $|x^2-1 |\le1/2$.

Comment: There are errors in the formula after Edit... In each integral, it is $(e^{i x(1-p)}+ e^{i x(-1-p)})$, and $1/(2\pi\sqrt{2})$ should also be in front of the second integral.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.

Comment: You can now group together the terms with $\frac{1}{1-p}$ for example.